# Group y axis values of plots in gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-wrap

I have provided sample data in below to reproduce the results:

```
dat <- data.frame(dataset=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C"),
                  tis=c("T1", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2"),
                  path=c("p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p3", "p1" ),
                  NS=c(1.1, 1.2, -0.5, -1.4, -1.6, 0.9, 0.8),
                  min=c(1, 0.4, -0.8, -2, -2, -0.1, 1.5),
                  max=c(2, 2, 0, -1, -0.3, 1.6, 2.1),
                  category=c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c1"))
```

So what I want to do to have separated errorbar plots grouped based on *tis* column. So basically, for this data I have two plots. Then I use grid extra to put these plots beside each other using below codes:

```
plots_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(tis) %>%
  group_split() %>% lapply(function(plotDat){
    
    ggplot(plotDat, aes(x=NS, y=path, group=dataset, col=dataset, fill=dataset)) +
      theme_minimal() + 
      geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1,1), colour="#FA8072", linetype = "longdash") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), colour="grey", linetype = "solid") +
      geom_errorbarh(height=.3, aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), position = position_dodge(0.7)) + theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
            plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5), "pt"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            text = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "top") + 
      labs(x = "NS", title = plotDat$tis) + 
      xlim(-2.5, 2.5) 
  })
```

and gridextra:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = c(
  list(
    ggplot(plots_dat[[1]]$data, aes(y = path, x = "")) +  labs(y = "Path", title = "", x = "") + theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(5,0,5,5), "pt"), text = element_text(size = 14))
    
  ),
  plots_dat
), nrow = 1, widths = c(1.1, rep(1, length(plots_dat))))
```

Everything works perfect as I see the below result:
[image]

now what I want as extra work, (1) I want to somehow have a kind of grouping on the y-axis based on 'category' column. I tried to use facet_wrap but it throws me error. I am skeptical that I am using it correctly. and (2) I want to have one row with grey background and the next one white and the same pattern for the next rows in the y-axis.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: No idea or guide?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a option using `ggplot` and `facet_grid` to create all the features in one graph:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=NS, y=path, group=dataset, col=dataset, fill=dataset))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.7)) +
  annotate('rect', xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin=1.5, ymax=2.5, alpha=0.2, fill="grey60")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1,1), colour="#FA8072", linetype = "longdash") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0), colour="grey", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_errorbarh(height=.3, aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), position = position_dodge(0.7))+
  facet_grid(category~tis)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,5,5), "pt"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.position = "top")+
  labs(y = "Path", title = "", x = "")
```

Here is the plot:
[Facet plot with grey background by row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bnVn.png)

Adding `annotate` to create the grey rectangle dividing 'rows'

```
annotate('rect', xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin=1.5, ymax=2.5, alpha=0.2, fill="grey60")
```

And the `facet_grid` to plot the data separated by `category` on the *y-axis* and `tis` on the *x-axis*

```
facet_grid(category~tis)
```